# sql - frequency of value over a time period (e.g. last week, last month, last year)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 relevant columns, name and date. I'm interested in creating new columns that track how many times a name has been recorded in the past week, past month, and past year.

I'm doing it clumsily by creating a new table for each time period, e.g.:

```
create table past_week as
select name, date, count(*) as past_week
from original_table
where date between date - interval '7 days' and date
group by name, date
order by date
```

Then I join that table with my original table:

```
select * 
from original_table o
    left join past_week pw on o.name = p.name and o.date = pw.date
```

Is there a better way to do this without creating new tables or joining the original table with itself? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course there is. What's your database?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create an extra table, though you necessarily need to join the table with itself -- at least a grouped version of itself.

In the second query just replace your `past_week` table with the first query, as in:

```
select * 
  from original_table o
  left join (
    select name, date, count(*) as past_week
      from original_table
      where date between date - interval '7 days' and date
      group by name, date
    ) pw on o.name = p.name and o.date = pw.date
```

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of the join with itself. Essentially you have two separate levels of aggregation: 1) Plain rows, 2) Counting rows during last week (grouping). I don't see how you can work some other magic here. What's your concern? Performance, complexity during maintenance, other?

Comment: Just new-ish to SQL and trying to learn best practices. I accepted your answer.

Comment: I went through the output of this query and my original query and I realized that it's not doing what I intended for it to do - it's just grouping on the date and returning the count for that date, i.e. "where date between date - interval '7 days' and date" always returns true. Do you have any suggestions for how to group together with previous dates within a week?

Answer (score 0):

A single-value subquery can be used in the SELECT:

```
select name, date,
(
  select count(*)
    from original o2
   where o2.name = o1.name
     and o2.date <@ daterange(o1.date - 7, o1.date)
) as past_week
from original o1
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```